# What's the difference between ATI FGLRX drivers and the "post release update" driver?

Tags: drivers, xorg, ati, fglrx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between the 2 FGLRX graphics drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66707/differences-between-the-2-fglrx-graphics-drivers)

So here's the deal: Fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10, got some basic applications like Code::Blocks, Wine, and such. I go to download the FGLRX drivers because the open source ones don't seem to work to well.

In my list of Additional Drivers (jockey), I have two options. The plain ATi/AMD FGLRX Driver, and another labeled something along the lines of ATi/AMD FGLRX Driver (post release update). The plain FGLRX driver installs just fine, but the post update gives me an error when I attempt to install it. Here's the log file: pastebin.com/rJMSkXwU

Why can I not install what I assume is a helpful update to the FGLRX dirver?

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/66707/differences-between-the-2-fglrx-graphics-drivers

Comment: This should not have been closed. The original title was by no means a duplicate, but a question concerning a bug with installing the post-release FGLRX driver.