# ATI/AMD Catalyst 11.9 drivers?

Tags: drivers

I'm thinking of downloading the drivers stated in the title but i've "heard" that it's not compatible with the latest ubuntu version. Is that true?

Comment: Stick to the repo drivers for now and use the 'post updates' package to upgrade.  I have heard things about unity and 11.9 and I like a working system, so I stayed away for now.

Comment: Ok. I tried to download the ATI/AMD Proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates) but when i press Activate it says: "sorry installation of this driver failed : please have a look at the log for details: /var/log/jockey.log

Comment: the post update drivers **are** 11.9, dont use them!

Comment: Yeah, i'm running the other one now (older one i suppose) and it works fine. Thanks everyone for the help :)

Comment: have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66707/differences-between-the-2-fglrx-graphics-drivers), dont use 11.9 for now because of the problems ppl are having. `post-release` is 11.9!

Comment: @Oskar mark it answered then, gl with your ati drivers :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the latest drivers ATI drivers give more problems than the previous ones specially using Gnome3 desktop. Its an ATI thing.

I would wait before using 11.9 packages on 11.10.

Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66707/differences-between-the-2-fglrx-graphics-drivers) to see the difference between available driver versions in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems. Use the 11.8 which come with the installaton of 11.10. Even these have problems especially with multi monitors support. In case you run into problems with multi monitor support in 11.10 [check this out](http://blog.jvc26.org/2011/09/29/multimonitor-ubuntu-oneiric-fglrx).