# Laptop over heating after 13.04. Video driver?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP ProBook 6465g, **Radeon HD 6520g**.

Now my laptop runs super hot, lag/no response from games, cpu at 80-100% (even when doing simple tasks) and the fans are going crazy.
I have a feeling that this must be something with my video driver?

Im currently using X.OrgXserver- AMD/AATI display driver.(open source) --which was set by default)

The two other options to choose from in "Software & Updates" is:
-Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates(proprietary) ..and
-Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx(proprietary)

I have tested both, but cant tell one was better than the other..

I've looked for a solution at the AMD sites and other forums, but no go.

Please help!!

Comment: Are you positive that you rebooted after applying the changes?

Comment: I did not reboot after --Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx(proprietary), but I did after the one with -update- , whats the difference of those?

Comment: Try activating `Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx(proprietary)` and reboot. Is the problem solved?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/66707/differences-between-the-2-fglrx-graphics-drivers explaining that question

Comment: yep, my computer seems to be running a lot better now. CPU does not jump that much anymore, and the temperature is also getting lower. Strange thing that the driver without "update" did better than the other then? There is one thing that bothers me tho, I cant play Dota2 on either of the drivers above. Lag and freeze :/ I could play that game nearly flawlessly in Windows. Anyways, Thanks guys.

Comment: Hmm... probably a setting in Dota like not using OpenGL or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate "Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx(proprietary)" and reboot. It seems that the drivers were not properly activated with the later version, and they wouldn't be activated anyway without a reboot.