# What is the difference between fglrx and fglrx-updates?

Tags: fglrx

What is the difference between the two ATI drivers `fglrx` and `fglrx-updates`, and what one should I install with a machine with an AMD R7 260X video card? I have found outdated information on the Steam Forums that said there were the same driver, and where can I find up to date information on these two drivers?

Comment: fglrx is the original driver available for 14.04, fglrx-updates will be updated as new versions are released/tested/added. Check also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66707/differences-between-the-2-fglrx-graphics-drivers

Comment: It no longer matters once you move past 14.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/744057/11522

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have tried both on Ubuntu 14.04, They were the same driver.  The "updates" version might be updated regularly, while the the non-"update" version will stay the same through out the release.

Comment: This needs clarification. It's not a bad answer, but this question is the first one that comes up when I google "fglrx vs fglrx-updates" and it doesn't convincingly answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

To see the differences between *fglrx* and *fglrx-updates*, check this:

- http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=fglrx
- http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=fglrx-updates

For example, on *vivid* release, *git sha* is not the same between *fglrx* and *fglrx-updates*. But *fglrx-update* has not been updated yet (while I am writing) to *15.7*

That means *fglrx-updates* is maybe more updated than *fglrx*, but if you want to stick to the edge, download the latest driver on [AMD website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)