# Can't install AMD drivers ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, fglrx, amd-graphics

So when i try to install AMD driver from their website it always give me that error:

- Please install the required pre-requisites before proceeding with AMD
  Catalyst installation. Please check file
  usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details.

I already have installed all stuff from log, but there is one thing that I don't know how to fix :
**(log)**

- NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for
  installation, install them in the order as per the log file to
  resolve package-dependency issues. fglrx installation requires that
  the system has kernel headers. 
  /lib/modules/4.2.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be
  found on this system. Install kernel headers using the command
  **apt-get install linux-headers-4.2.0-41-generic.**

Comment: You do not need to install drivers form "their site". Run `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates` and reboot. That will install drivers.

Comment: [Fglrx / Catalyst isn't supported anymore on 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/744050/im-using-ubuntu-16-04-and-theres-no-fglrx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name is actually `linux-headers-generic-lts-wily` that you want to install. This should pull in the headers and keep them updated with kernel updates you install.