# Radeon Graphics Card not working in 16.04

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

Currently the problems are: 1. can only log in with recovery mode / nouveau, 2. poor screen resolution, and 3. screen display shows "built in display" only.

My graphics card is: 1024Mb ATi Radeon HD 5770 PCI-Express VGA Card. It was working fine before moving from 14.04 to 16.04 yesterday.

I have an Intel CPU and I believe I am using the open source radeon driver.

Please, could someone tell me how to get the graphics card working again?

When I run this command: `dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'`

I get this response:

```
[    1.536906] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    1.586158] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    1.586239] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
[   44.543359] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[   44.543388] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

When I enter `lshw -c video`

I get:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fbdc0000-fbddffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fbd00000-fbd1ffff
```

The output of `sudo cat /etc/default/grub` can be seen here http://paste.ubuntu.com/22074912/

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

To start with, let's make sure you have a AMD CPU. Run this in a terminal:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq
```

If this shows AMD, then you need to correct the drivers.

To get the correct drivers, first, select "Do not use this device" option. Then, from a terminal, run:

```
sudo apt-get remove intel-microcode iucode-tool
```

Now, run:

```
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode
```

Then, go again to the "Additional Drivers" tab, and select proprietary option.

**NOTE**: In case you are not aware, proprietary driver for AMD **graphic cards** (fglrx) are not longer supported in Ubuntu 16.04. Open-source drivers are then used by default. That is why you do not see any propeietary driver in that window, as you probably saw in your previous Ubuntu (14.04?). See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744050/im-using-ubuntu-16-04-and-theres-no-fglrx) and [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04) for more information.

Comment: Hi @luchonacho , thanks for your response!


I have an intel CPU, here's the output of 'cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq':


'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         750  @ 2.67GHz'


What should I do to ensure I have the correct drivers for my Radeon graphics card?


Currently the problems are: 1. can only log in with recovery mode, 2. poor screen resolution, and 3. screen display shows "built in display" only.

Comment: Aha! So then, there is nothing wrong with that additional drivers bit! You probably have the correct drivers already, by default. If this is true, you have a different problem. To confirm, please add the output of `lshw -c video` to your question. (To format as code, select text and press Ctrl+K)

Comment: Ok, drivers are fine. There is another problem. Look into your `/etc/default/grub` file, and look for the word `nomodeset`. Delete that. Then save, run `sudo update-grub` from a terminal, and restart.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do this. There was no mention of the word `nomodeset` in my `/etc/default/grub` file unfortunately. So I tried running sudo update-grub anyway, and restarting, but alas the exact same problem remains.

What do you think the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: Mmm, can you add the output of `sudo cat /etc/default/grub` to your question? To avoid adding too much test, copy your text [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and add the link only.

Comment: Hi @luchonacho , I've pasted the file contents. If I have the correct drivers, should I update the title of the question? Any suggestions for this?