# Black screen booting in ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, 16.10, recovery-mode

My hardware is Mother Board ASUS M5A 78L-M (Graphics Card RS780L [Radeon 3000]) and OS is Ubuntu 16.04

When i boot normally I have an black screen, but when i boot in recovery mode and then i choose “resume” option the system works fine with no problem in graphics mode.

I have tried fix broken packages and installing Ubuntu 16.10 with no changes in behaviour.

What could i do to get more information or boot right?

Thank you

Comment: This is an unusual problem, and I don't think it's a duplicate of the usual "black screen" question because it is possible to circumvent the black screen by choosing recovery mode and then resume.

Comment: When black screen appears there is a windows from monitor hadrware that says  "no signal"

Comment: The computer shows rigth the first splash screen to modify BIOS. And "No signal" message appear uast when I try to start normally, not in recovery mode.

Comment: I found in the dmesg output the error  [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module! and I tried theses two solutions [Black screen booting in ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867491/black-screen-booting-in-ubuntu-16-04-and-16-10?noredirect=1#comment1343049_867491) and [Radeon Graphics Card not working in 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/806281/radeon-graphics-card-not-working-in-16-04) with no success.

Comment: How can  I include the dmesg output here? Tnahks.