# Ubuntu 16.04.1 ATI GPU error (No UMS support)

Tags: boot, 16.04, drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

I turned off my computer yesterday, and today when I turn it on my Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot (I'm using windows now, and my Ubuntu 14.04 works as well). It gives me a black screen. I can, however, boot on "recovery mode". As far as I have searched, this is a problem with my ATI/AMD Radeon GPU (HD 5850). Although this is weird to me, since untill yesterday it was working fine. I have removed two programs I installed yesterday, but no good.

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806281/radeon-graphics-card-not-working-in-16-04) post, I have managed to get the information below, it is of any use.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'name' |uniq
```

**Output**: *model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         930  @ 2.80GHz*

```
sudo lshw -c video 

 *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cypress PRO [Radeon HD 5850]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fbbc0000-fbbdffff ioport:b000(size=256) memory:fbba0000-fbbbffff
```

The "main" error message:

```
dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'

[    1.933680] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    1.967799] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    1.967870] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
[   15.482866] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[   15.482888] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

The output of `sudo cat /etc/default/grub`
can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23918369/

I'm aware that the *fglrx* of AMD GPU is not supported on Ubuntu 16.04.1, but since when I first installed it (back in August 2016) it has worked with no problem. Out of nowhere this problem came and now I can't boot it. Any help?

Comment: Ok, after several trials, I've managed to boot properly. Apparently my boot option in the GRUB menu had been set to a previous kernel version (4.4.0-53) somehow. The correct (and most up to date I have) is 4.4.0-59.  After changing this in grub-customizer, Ubuntu 16.04.1 boots correctly. However, it complains about some internal error every time I boot, which I think is related to the GPU error (but I ubuntu won't report me the error, or give any log). Anyway, this is still bothering my mind, and if anyone has an explanation it could be useful for future users.