# best ubuntu release for amd a10 cpu, asus a88x-pro, g.skill ddr3 2400

Tags: system-installation

To witch release has the most stable video and what driver and where to get them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) and possible duplicate of [I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and there's no fglrx!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/744050/im-using-ubuntu-16-04-and-theres-no-fglrx)

Answer (score 0):

I use an AMD A8 APU with Ubuntu 14.04 and the open source Radion driver included in the distribution and this works well.
If you are doing something very graphics intense (like gaming) you may need to use the fgixr (ana AMD Catalyst) This can be downloaded from [AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx), but personally, I would only try this if the open source driver is not good enough for you (I find the open source driver works well with home cinema).

Personally, I would start by installing 16.04 but note that the [fgixr driver may not work with 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744050/im-using-ubuntu-16-04-and-theres-no-fglrx) so if you go down this route and the open source driver is not good enough for you, you may have no upgrade route