# Installing Ubuntu Drivers

Tags: drivers, 16.04, dell

I would like to install AMD drivers for my Dell Latitude E6540, but I couldn't find any. Here are my system specifications. http://paste.ubuntu.com/23189499/

Thanks

Comment: The Software And Updates app has an Additional Drivers tab. Did you look there?

Comment: Yes, but all I see is intel-microcode driver

Comment: IN that case you have an Intel cpu. You can confirm this with the command `sudo lshw -C cpu` Why do you need AMD drivers?

Comment: So I can play video games, I believe I have hybrid graphics

Comment: You can find that out with the command `sudo lshw -C Display` the output will tell you what display adapters are in your system

Comment: When I type that, I get this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23189539/

Comment: But look what happens when I type lspci | grep VGA I get this
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23189543/

Comment: Yup that looks like hybrid graphics alright.

Answer (score 3):

You're running Ubuntu 16.04, so the essential drivers are already loaded on to your computer.

As of 16.04, [AMD pulled `fglrx`](https://askubuntu.com/a/744057/208574) from the repositories, making it unavailable for use. This move was made both because the X11 backend changed things that broke `fglrx`, and as a result of AMD's encouragement for people to move over to the open-source `radeon` and `amdgpu` drivers. These open-source drivers are automatically installed with Ubuntu, with the proper one automatically being chosen for your hardware.

If you actually need the full support that the `fglrx` package gives out (in most cases, this is untrue), you have no choice but to go back to Ubuntu 14.04 or another `fglrx`-supported version. Alternatively, you can just wait for the open-source drivers to just get better, which they inevitably will.

Comment: I don't really know what to do to be honest with you. I was hoping to test the performance of a game. And yes, it does support Linux

Comment: @mohamadc See if the game works, and check it's framerate. If it keeps above a respectable level (usually 60, may be 30 or even 24 for some), you'll be fine.

Comment: Whenever I use the integrated graphics card, i always get shitty results (pardon my french)

Comment: I'm getting 35 fps with the integrated graphics, but back on Windows when I would use the AMD graphics I would get 60 fps constant. Talking about minecraft by the way

Comment: @mohamadc Hybrid graphics are a weird child of computing that we could probably do without. Unfortunately, the situation with them makes it so Linux won't get proper support for them for a *long* time. Honestly, I'd recommend you dual-boot and use Windows for gaming.

Comment: also how do i check if the amd open source driver is installed?

Comment: if the essential drivers really are loaded onto the computer, then how can I run a program with the discrete GPU?