# Where to find working drivers for my I7 6700 and R9 390

Tags: drivers, intel, amd-graphics

I'm trying to install drivers for my I7 6700 and R9 390, but I never can make them work together.

Black screen, purple screen, no screen.

So where can I find working drivers for those 2 hardware items for the latest Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

Linux, unlike Windows, has a vastly different concept of "drivers." Most are built into the kernel itself, blocking the need for manual installation.

Now, more specifically to your question. Your processor, being a processor, requires **no extra drivers** on your system. The kernel has everything you need pre-packaged.

As for your graphics card, that gets a bit complicated. In olden times, there existed a package called `fglrx`, which was the set of drivers for Radeon graphics cards. However, as of 16.04, these drivers [no longer exist](https://askubuntu.com/a/744057/208574). Instead, the system will automatically install (at initial OS installation/configuration) the appropriate driver, being either `amdgpu` or `radeon`. If you feel as though your system has installed the wrong driver somehow, you can manually force it by running ***one*** of the below commands:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-radeon # Radeon Driver
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu # Misc AMD Driver
```

Typically, you would never have to touch this. It is very likely that your problem is being caused by something else that manifests itself in a black screen.

I would recommend checking [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/208574) first, and seeing if anything there helps you.