# DKMS issue with 'sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*'

Tags: fglrx

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fglrx-14.10.1006.1001
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'fglrx-14.10.1006.1001'
```

I am trying to completely remove the last remnants of the current ATI/AMD FGLRX driver I downloaded from them.  When I run the above command, I get the above output.  How can I remove this entry from DKMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that is what's causing the problem here, but you probably don't mean to have the pattern expanded by the shell, so you should quote it:

If you have a file `fglrx-14.10.1006.1001` in the current directory,
the command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

gets expanded to

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-14.10.1006.1001
```

which would explain why `apt-get` is looking for that package.

Quote the pattern like this to prevent the shell interpreting the `*`:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge "fglrx*"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess it is not really installed anymore, but I would like to remove that entry if possible.  Just seems odd it is there.  When I installed and uninstalled the driver, I remember DKMS was having an issue with that file name so I figured the two were related somehow.  Can the entry be removed?

Comment: Thanks!  I did have a folder in the home directory I was in with that name.  After I deleted it, the original command I posted earlier worked without issue.

Comment: Done.  Mind if I ask you one more question?  In Additional Drivers, what is the difference between fglrx and fglrx-updates?

Comment: I don't know - but it's better to ask it as a separate question anyway. Then, an answer can help others too.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66707/differences-between-the-2-fglrx-graphics-drivers